# Support Vector Machine - R code - Predict Residual error of Time Series

Tags: r, svm, prediction

I'm trying to predict residual error of time series using R code. My dataset have the following two columns (I will put a sample with the first 10 rows):

```
Observation Residuals
1   -0,087527458
2   -0,06907199
3   -0,066604145
4   -0,07796713
5   -0,081723932
6   -0,094046868
7   -0,101535816
8   -0,101884203
9   -0,11131246
10  -0,092548176
```

For the prediction I'm building a Support Vector Machine using R:

```
# Load the data from the csv file
dataDirectory <- "C://"  
data <- read.csv(paste(dataDirectory, "Data_SVM_Test.csv", sep=""),sep=";", header = TRUE)
head(data)
# Plot the data 
plot(data, pch=16)

# Create a linear regression model
model <- lm(Residuals ~ Observation, data)

# Add the fitted line
abline(model)

predictedY <- predict(model, data)

# display the predictions
points(data$Observation, predictedY, col = "blue", pch=4) 

# This function will compute the RMSE
rmse <- function(error)
{
  sqrt(mean(error^2))
}

error <- model$residuals  # same as data$Y - predictedY
predictionRMSE <- rmse(error)   # 5.70377

plot(data, pch=16)

plot.new()
# svr model ==============================================
if(require(e1071)){ 
  model <- svm(Residuals ~ Observation , data)

  predictedY <- predict(model, data)

  points(data$Observation, predictedY, col = "red", pch=4)

  # /!\ this time  svrModel$residuals  is not the same as data$Y - predictedY
  # so we compute the error like this
  error <- data$Residuals - predictedY  
  svrPredictionRMSE <- rmse(error)  # 3.157061 
}
```

When I execute the above code I am getting the following error message and without any output:

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(data$Residuals, predictedY) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Anyone have an idea how can solve this error?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `svm` for classification, the output is of type factor. This is from the documentation:

> Output of svm: A vector of predicted values (for classification: a vector of labels, for density estimation: a logical vector).

This can be seen from the following example:

```
library(e1071)
model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
> str( predict(model, iris))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

It is the same for your data. Levels show that `PredictedY` is a factor:

```
> predictedY <- predict(model, df)
> predictedY
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8            9           10 
-0,087527458  -0,06907199 -0,066604145  -0,07796713 -0,081723932 -0,094046868 -0,101535816 -0,101884203  -0,11131246 -0,092548176 
Levels: -0,066604145 -0,06907199 -0,07796713 -0,081723932 -0,087527458 -0,092548176 -0,094046868 -0,101535816 -0,101884203 -0,11131246
```

In your line of code `predictedY <- predict(model, data)`, `predictedY` is of type factor. If you try to deduct a number from a factor (or vice versa) you get your error:

```
> 1:10 - as.factor(1:10)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(1:10, as.factor(1:10)) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

If you want to make it work, you need to convert factors into numbers using `as.numeric`. `1:10 - as.numeric(as.factor(1:10))`.

I don't know what your data looks like, but I judging from the title of the question `svm` is probably not a good idea for time series.

Comment: many thanks about your answer. So you recommend to convert the column Residuals to numeric, right? In the begining of the question I put the my dataset :)

Comment: I recommend using `error <- data$Residuals - as.numeric(predictedY) ` because `predictedY` will be of class factor when you predict with svm.